# Encounter very weird problem with loopback4 (model wasn't really working well)

Tags: loopback4

For some unknown reason `this.toEntities` return my object to `undefined`
[image]

I dig few more and found out that `return new this.entityClass(model.toObject())` return all data to `undefined`. Please have a look at the console area.
[image]

im running loobpack with this command line
`lb-tsc --copy-resources && tsc-watch --target ESNext --outDir ./dist --onSuccess "node --inspect ."`

this is my packages version

```
macOS: Sonoma 14.1
node: 16.20.2

➜ pnpm list
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

loopack4-starter-pack@0.0.1 /Users/haziq.jasni/work/cgss-be

dependencies:
@loopback/authentication 10.1.1  @loopback/rest-explorer 6.1.1    bcrypt 5.1.0                     jsonwebtoken 9.0.0
@loopback/authorization 0.14.1   @loopback/security 0.10.3        casbin 5.19.1                    lodash 4.17.21
@loopback/boot 6.1.1             @loopback/service-proxy 6.1.1    check-password-strength 2.0.7    loopback-connector-mysql 6.1.0
@loopback/core 5.1.1             @types/bcrypt 5.0.0              date-fns 2.30.0                  nodemailer 6.9.0
@loopback/repository 6.1.1       @types/jsonwebtoken 9.0.1        debug 4.3.4                      tsconfig-paths 4.1.2
@loopback/rest 13.1.1            @types/nodemailer 6.4.7          email-validator 2.0.4            tslib 2.0.0

devDependencies:
@loopback/build 10.1.1          @types/lodash 4.14.197          eslint 8.53.0                   tsc-watch 6.0.4
@loopback/eslint-config 14.0.2  @types/mocha 10.0.1             pm2 5.3.0                       typescript 5.1.6
@loopback/testlab 6.1.1         @types/node 16.18.61            source-map-support 0.5.21
@types/debug 4.1.8              dotenv 16.0.3                   tsc-alias 1.8.2
```

---

I ran few more test like below

```
 console.log(
      await this.emissionRepository.count(),
      await this.emissionRepository.find(),
      await this.plantActualDetailRepository.execute(`SELECT * FROM User`)
)
```

[image: ![image](https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/assets/9023187/a2c2d63f-026a-45f6-b8e4-e788a8180a30)]

[image]

So if my understanding correctly my model is the one that doesn't really work well?. Since vanilla sql works perfectly.

```
import { Entity, model, property } from '@loopback/repository'

@model()
export class Emission extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number

  @property({ type: 'number' })
  no_of_year: number

  @property({ type: 'number' })
  co2_actual_emission: number

  @property({ type: 'number' })
  emissionId?: number

  constructor(data?: Partial<Emission>) {
    super(data)
  }
}

export interface EmissionRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type EmissionWithRelations = Emission & EmissionRelations
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer by changing to this command lind (--target 2021)

```
   $ lb-tsc --copy-resources && tsc-watch --target es2021 --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"node .\"
```

And i can confirm that using es2022 will result in undefined model as stated above